# Symfony 3 twig file with render controller

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig

I've a problem with Symfony.

I've a VideoController that renders a twig page.

This twig page includes another twig page that has a rendercontroller. With this render controller, the route crash and it says that the "video" variable that I send with the first controller doesn't exists. What's wrong?

This is the code for VideoController:

```
public function getVideo(Request $request, $id) {
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $video = $entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Video')->getVidById($id);
    return $this->render('vids/videos.html.twig', ['video' => $video]); //Needs improvements
}
```

**videos.html.twig:**

```
{% block main %}
<center>
     <video controls style="width:720px;height:360px;" poster="poster.png">
     <source src="{{ video.link }}" type="video/mp4;" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" />
     </video>
     {{ include ("comments/comment.html.twig") }}
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

**comment.html.twig:**

```
{% block comment %}
<br><br>
  <center>
    {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Video:commentVideo')) }}
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

**CommentController:**

```
class CommentsController extends Controller 
{
    /*
     * Check if session is valid. If so, user can comment. SECURITY SYSTEM NEEDS TO BE DEVELOPED!!!
     * @Route("/", name="comment")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function commentVideoAction(Request $request) {
        $comment = new Comment();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($comment)
        ->add('text', TextType::class)
        ->add('Invia Commento', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $comment = $form->getData();
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($comment);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->render('vids/videos.html.twig');
        }
        return $this->render('vids/videos.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
    }
}
```

Comment: which variable make error ?

Comment: "video". I've also inserted this information in the question!

Comment: You need to pass the variable `$video` in the `CommentController` to the template as well...

Answer (score 0):

In your render (commentVideoAction), you have the twig file "vids/videos.html.twig" and you don't pass the video variable. I think you use the bad template. (

Comment: no need to pass the variable here because he don't use it in comment controller

Comment: Yes but in your template "videos.html.twig", there is a video variable...

Comment: given by the video controller here : `$this->render('vids/videos.html.twig', ['video' => $video])`

Comment: Yes but the method commentVideoAction not pass this information. YOu have to regive this information to your controller action.

Comment: Damn, didn't saw that comment controller render the video template ... i think he made a mistake here ....

Comment: Yes i think he did a mistake on the template name. He doesn't need to include the comment template, juste render the controller action comment.

Comment: Should be a comment. Make it more into answer cause this is calling for downvotes

Answer (score -1):

I think there s a mistake in your VideoController.

Try with `public function getVideoAction(Request $request, $id)` instead of just getVideo

And your structure is bad, you have a loop in your controllers, try like this:

videos.html.twig:

```
{% block main %}
<center>
     <video controls style="width:720px;height:360px;" poster="poster.png">
     <source src="{{ video.link }}" type="video/mp4;" codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2" />
     </video>
     {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Video:commentVideo')) }}
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

comment.html.twig:

```
{% block comment %}
<br><br>
  <center>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</center>
{% endblock %}
```

CommentController:

```
class CommentsController extends Controller 
{
/*
 * Check if session is valid. If so, user can comment. SECURITY SYSTEM NEEDS TO BE DEVELOPED!!!
 * @Route("/", name="comment")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function commentVideoAction(Request $request) {
    $comment = new Comment();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($comment)
    ->add('text', TextType::class)
    ->add('Invia Commento', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $comment = $form->getData();
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($comment);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->render('vids/videos.html.twig');
    }
    return $this->render('vids/comment.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
));
}
}
```